# how to convert bigIncrements('id') to uuid('id') as the primary key?

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, uuid

Currently, our system has BIGINTS as primary keys but now we are moving to GUIDS/UUIDS and we need to convert our tables. I thought something like this in a new migration may work but unfortunately, it complains about the fact that the ID column already exists.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropPrimary('PRIMARY');
        $table->dropColumn('id');

        $table->uuid('id');
        $table->primary('id');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->primary('id');
    });
}
```

Is there a proper way to do this switch in a Laravel migration?

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Change `PRIMARY` to `users_id_primary` and separate the operations:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropPrimary('users_id_primary');
        $table->dropColumn('id');
    });

    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id');
        $table->primary('id');
    });
}
```

Comment: I get the following error

   `[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'PRIMARY'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table `us
  ers` drop primary key)`



  `[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'PRIMARY'; check that column/key exists`



  `[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'PRIMARY'; check that column/key exists`

Comment: @SegFaultDev that's because you didn't use my code, but you used yours.

Comment: I was using the code you provided. I will try again just to confirm.

Comment: @SegFaultDev no you've used your code because the error you've shown says `PRIMARY` and not `users_id_primary`

Comment: Hey Alexey. My apologies. That specific error did not come from the code you posted. Here is the error --- `[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it mus
  t be defined as a key (SQL: alter table `users` drop primary key)`
`[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it mus
  t be defined as a key`

Comment: `[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it mus
  t be defined as a key` 

With the following code.

`Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropPrimary('users_id_primary');
            $table->dropColumn('id');
        });

        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id');
            $table->primary('id');
        });`

Comment: Try to remove `$table->primary('id');` line.